# Proving by induction $\sum_{j = b}^a\frac{j!}{b!(j-b)!} = \frac{(a+1)!}{(b+1)!(a-b)!}$

Tags: induction

I am only recently studying how to write proofs, and as an exercise I set off to prove the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j = b}^a\frac{j!}{b!(j-b)!} = \frac{(a+1)!}{(b+1)!(a-b)!} 
\end{equation}

The strategy I chose for proving this is induction. **I performed induction on $\boldsymbol{a}$** —the upper limit of the summation— **while considering an arbitrary non-negative integer $\boldsymbol{b}$ as the lower limit of the summation.** The base case is $a = b$, which is very trivial to verify, and then I performed the inductive step as follows.

**Inductive hypothesis: $\boldsymbol{\sum_{j = b}^{a - 1}\frac{j!}{b!(j-b)!} = \frac{a!}{(b+1)!(a-1-b)!}}$**

**Inductive step:**

\begin{align}
\sum_{j = b}^a\frac{j!}{b!(j-b)!} &= \sum_{j = b}^{a - 1}\bigg(\frac{j!}{b!(j-b)!}\bigg) + \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!} \\ \\
&= \frac{a!}{(b+1)!(a-1-b)!} + \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!} \\ \\
&= \frac{a!(a-b)}{(b+1)b!(a-b)!} + \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!} \\ \\
&= \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}\bigg(\frac{a-b}{b+1} + 1\bigg) \\ \\
&= \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}\bigg(\frac{a+1}{b+1}\bigg) \\ \\
&= \frac{(a+1)!}{(b+1)!(a-b)!}
\end{align}

Here's my question: **does this already conclude the demonstration, or is it necessary to do an analogous procedure with $\boldsymbol{b}$ —that is, consider $\boldsymbol{a}$ to be fixed on some arbitrary value and then perform induction on $\boldsymbol{b}$—?**

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to perform induction on b.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).